# using telnet to connect to a ssh based server

Tags: ssh, telnet

Is it possible to use tunneling to connect to a ssh server via telnet? I'm using an API that can only telnet to a host, but that host will only accept ssh connections. If it is possible, what do I need to do to set that up?

Answer (score 1):

Use netcat and ssh

```
$ nc -l -p 12345 -c "ssh someone@remotehost.com"
```

make sure that you have RSA auth setup, since you cannot enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

i think what would work would be to run a telnet server on a local port on the host and use ssh to forward that locally where the api could connect to it; but that's just a bit silly